# Wiiremock http fail errors

Tags: java, load-testing, wiremock

I wrote the following wiremock code for a HTTP request for load testing in the Jmeter:

I am getting the following errors when I run it in the eclipse:

Can anyone help me solving this?

Comment: still having the issue?

Comment: What code?.....

Answer (score 2):

you have specified two different port numbers 8081, 8080

wiremock will run on specified port only, below code works on localhost:8080/abc/xyz

```
package com.wiremock;

import  com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer;
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock;
import 
com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.stubbing.StubMapping;
import static 
com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.*;


public class WireMockMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(8080);
    //configureFor("localhost", 8081);
    wireMockServer.start();
    StubMapping foo = WireMock.stubFor(get(urlPathEqualTo("/abc/xyz"))
            .willReturn(aResponse()
                    .withStatus(200)
                    .withBody("{\"message\": \"Hello World\"}")));

    wireMockServer.addStubMapping(foo);
}

}
```